# How to export breakpoints index into a vector from strucchange package?

Tags: r

I'm using the **strucchange** package in order to determine where my curve model segments.

My code looks like this:

```
l.fit <- loess(data$y~data$x)
px <- predict(l.fit,newdata=data$x)
bp <- breakpoints(px~1)
```

Now, the output of bp:

```
Optimal 6-segment partition: 

Call:
breakpoints.formula(formula = px ~ 1)

Breakpoints at observation number:
161 254 347 440 533 

Corresponding to breakdates:
0.2571885 0.4057508 0.5543131 0.7028754 0.8514377
```

The breakdates are kind of useless, as my x scale goes from 1 to 700 or so. But the breakpoints themselves are exactly what I want, specifically the last one, 533.

If i type:

```
bp[1]
```

I get:

```
$breakpoints
[1] 161 254 347 440 533
```

but if I try to assign `bp[1]` to a new vector, I get nothing. Is there anyway I can isolate the last breakpoint, i.e. 533, and assign it to a variable so I can plot a vertical line at the breakpoint? I need to do this for a couple hundred datasets, so being able to isolate the breakpoints would be really useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` extraction doesn't drop to the simpliest form, so it remains a list. Use `[[` or `$` extraction instead to get a numeric vector.

```
bps <- bp[[1]]
```

or

```
bps <- bp$breakpoints
```

To get the last one, you would need to either count its length and select the last one, or reverse it and select the first:

```
bps[length(bps)]
```

or

```
rev(bps)[1]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! bps<-bp$breakpoints worked perfectly!

Comment: Only if data$x is also a sequence 1:700 would this answer the last part correctly.

Comment: @DWin I'm not sure I follow you, are you suggesting `max(bps)` would be better?

Comment: @DWin The OP asked for the last value on the breakpoint vector, not the corresponding data value.

Comment: @James  But he also asked for something that could be used to position a vertical line. Sometimes we need to address the goal rather than the questioner's misunderstanding of the method.

Comment: @DWin So `max(data$x[bps])` would be better?

Comment: @James : Yes. That or `tail( data$x[bps], 1)`, or `data$x[ bps[length(bps] ]`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell whether you are so new at R that you think that the fact that executing this code should produce any console output:

```
vec <- bp[1]
```

What happens if you now type:

```
vec
```

You should be using either bp[["breakpoints"]][5] or bp$breakpoints[5] to get the last breakpoint. You would then want to use it as an index into data$x :

```
 data$x[ bp$breakpoints[5] ]
```

If you are doing this "programmatically" it might be safer to use the [["quoted-name"]] version of access, since the $ version has some under-appreciated gotcha's.